# Can't get Ubuntu to boot on Asus Zenbook ux500vz laptop

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, uefi

After updating my old windows 8 laptop to windows 10, it started freezing all the time.
I therefore decided to install ubuntu on it as the soul OS. 
I created a bootable USB with the 64 bit version of ubuntu on it. 
I successfully completed the installation, and this is where it all went south.
when i restarted the system the OS did not boot, I instead landed in the bios/UEFI menu, and there where no boot options what so ever. 
I afterwards plugged in the bootable usb, used the "try ubuntu without installing" option.
In there I ran the boot repair software, without any luck - same issue persisted.
I have been searching for an a solutions for this issue without much luck. 
I might think it has something to do with the UEFI, but I have disabled fast boot and secure boot control, still no luck. 
Boot repair gave me this URL as reference:
http://paste2.org/3ZKC01O1
I can't for the heck of me figure out how to fix this, have I done some form of irreparable damage, or can it be fixed?
BR.

Comment: Try entering your bios and having a look if you can find your Ubuntu entry there. If none can be found you could try reinstalling Ubuntu and performing a full wipe (without manually configuring the partitions). It might be that your windows 10 boot partition is still there depending on what options you selected previously.

Comment: Thanks for your response mate.  Even though I am not sure I fully understand it. I have been in my bios and under boot options priorities there are no options available?? And i have in fact been using the clean install option, where everything else should be wiped out.